# Your app(s) are using an unsafe implementation of the HostnameVerifier interface

Tags: android, security

I am using below code and using default hostname verifier. Now playstore is not letting me to update the app.

```
public static HttpClient getHttpsClient() {
    HostnameVerifier hostnameVerifier = org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER;

    HttpClient mHttpClient = null;
    HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();

    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, HTTP_TIMEOUT);
    DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
    SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
    SSLSocketFactory socketFactory = SSLSocketFactory.getSocketFactory();
    // X509HostnameVerifier hostnameVerifier = null;

    socketFactory
    .setHostnameVerifier((X509HostnameVerifier) hostnameVerifier);
    registry.register(new Scheme("http", new FakeSocketFactory(), 443));
    registry.register(new Scheme("https", PlainSocketFactory
            .getSocketFactory(), 80));

    SingleClientConnManager mgr = new SingleClientConnManager(client
            .getParams(), registry);
    mHttpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(mgr, client.getParams());
    final HttpParams params = mHttpClient.getParams();
    HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(hostnameVerifier);

    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, HTTP_TIMEOUT);
    HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, HTTP_TIMEOUT);
    HttpConnectionParams.setTcpNoDelay(httpParameters, true);
    ConnManagerParams.setTimeout(params, HTTP_TIMEOUT);
    return mHttpClient;

}
```

I got suggestion that i need to integrate

```
HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier()   {
        @Override
        public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession arg1) {
            if(hostname.equalsIgnoreCase("api.my.com") || hostname.equalsIgnoreCase("api.crashlytics.com") || hostname.equalsIgnoreCase("settings.crashlytics.com")){
                return true;
            }else {
                return false;
            }

        }
    });
```

I want to know how to integrate this into my code? And if is there any other solution please let me know.

Comment: It's easy, just replace your `SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER` with the safe implementation.

Comment: How to implement this into my code. thats what i want to know. When I am calling getHttpClient it returns mHttpClient and  domain veryfy true and false return late respond.

Comment: My app also rejected couldn't find a way

Comment: I am implementing volley now to solve this issue @TanmaySahoo

Comment: @Alpesh does it work in volley?